Complexity of Vertex Cover on Cubic Bridgeless Graph
Problem $P_1$: Given a cubic bridgeless graph $G=(V,E)$ consisting of $m$ vertices and $n$ edges, I want to know what is the complexity of the vertex cover problem on graph $G$.
The vertex cover problem on cubic (3-regular) graphs is NP-complete. Hence, the problem $P_1$ seems to be NP-complete too. Is it so? If yes, which NP-complete problem can we reduce to $P_1$ (and how) that proves the NP-completeness of $P_1$? Please cite the paper that is referred to.

You could look at the proof for 3-regular graphs, and see if the graphs there are bridgeless.

Thanks so much! The Garey Johnson Stockmeyer paper helped a lot.

You could mention what you found as an answer.
